# Can I use NBT tag values ​as command input?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use commands to detect when a player's bed is broken using the SpawnX, SpawnY, and SpawnZ NBT tags. It would look something like this:

```
/execute as @a unless block [SpawnX] [SpawnY] [SpawnZ] #minecraft:beds run [command]
```

I just want to know if there's a way to insert these NBT tag values ​​into the command, and if so, how?

I did also ask this question on the [Minecraft Forum](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/3161922-using-nbt-tag-values-as-command-input) but didn't receive any answers.